# PHPMailer Error 500.Stack trace: #0 {main}

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a PHP Mailer setup on my server for my website. However, I do not use composer so I did what the github page suggested:

```
require 'php/src/Exception.php';
require 'php/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'php/src/SMTP.php';
```

This is my entire mail script with my email and personal info removed:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'php/src/Exception.php';
require 'php/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'php/src/SMTP.php';

$errors = [];
$errorMessage = '';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if (empty($name)) {
        $errors[] = 'Name is empty';
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        $errors[] = 'Email is empty';
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = 'Email is invalid';
    }

    if (empty($message)) {
        $errors[] = 'Message is empty';
    }


    if (empty($errors)) {
        $toEmail = 'contact@[REMOVED]';
        $emailSubject = 'New email from your contant form';
        $headers = ['From' => $email, 'Reply-To' => $email, 'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'];

        $bodyParagraphs = ["Name: {$name}", "Email: {$email}", "Message:", $message];
        $body = join(PHP_EOL, $bodyParagraphs);

        if (mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $body, $headers)) {
            header('Location: [REMOVED]');
        } else {
            $errorMessage = 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again later';
        }
    } else {
        $allErrors = join('<br/>', $errors);
        $errorMessage = "<p style='color: red;'>{$allErrors}</p>";
    }
}

?>
```

These are the errors I am receiving:

```
[21-May-2022 23:07:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(php/src/Exception.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [REMOVED] on line 6
[21-May-2022 23:07:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'php/src/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in [REMOVED]:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in [REMOVED] on line 6
```

I apologize for removing some things, let me know if they are necessary to debug.
Again, I did not use composer or install anything special for this.

Comment: Does it work if you use Composer, which is the defacto standard method of installation?

Answer (score 1):

The files you are trying to load are not there. Download the files from the GitHub repo and put them in your `php/src` folder and your require statements will work.

Separately, learn how to use composer. It’s worth doing.

Comment: I did add those files. to my php/src. Those are the correct locations.

Comment: If the locations were correct, it would be finding them. It's possible your current working directory is not where you think it is, which will mean that relative paths don't work. Try prefixing them with `__DIR__ . '/'` to generate absolute paths relative to your script.

Comment: After I include all of them with DIR, should I change the requires to the file names along? For example, putting ```include __DIR__ . "/src/Exception.php"``` and then changing my ```require 'php/src/Exception.php';``` to ```require '/src/Exception.php';```

When I do either or, I get the error: ```PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/src/Exception.php'```

Comment: No, change them all to be like `require __DIR__ . '/php/src/Exception.php';`

Comment: I tried this, and got the error: ```PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception, because the name is already in use in /home/af5jxjdhmicu/sites/[removed]/public_html/php/src/Exception.php on line 0``` 

I continued to get HTTP Error 500 with this, but I changed require to require_once and that got rid of error 500 and any errors showing up in my error_log.php. However, I am still not receiving any test emails.

Comment: This is another lesson in why learning to use composer is important! If you’re getting 500 errors, the full details of them will be in your web server logs.